# writing a query to fetch data in a specific way

Tags: php, mysql

table name : resources

```
res_id | first_name
   1      clyde
   2      John
   3      Rachel
   4      Jason
   5      Rasmon
   6      Pierson
   7      Jamson
   8      Radamel
```

table name : probation_hr

```
probation_id | res_id | month_id | hr_id
   1             1         M1        4
   2             1         M2        4
   3             2         M1        4
   4             2         M2        4
```

table name: probation_feedback

```
 prob_id | reviewer_id | res_id
  1           6          null
  1           7          null
  1           8          null
  1           null       1
```

res_id not null in probation feedback table means probationer has filled up his feedback

given a set of resource_id's , i want to fetch his details as follows

```
resources.first_name, 
probation_hr.month_id,
probation_hr.probation_id, 
probation_hr.hr_id (also get this id's first name from resources table),
and lastly get all records from probation_feedback table where 
probation_hr.probation_id = probation_feedback.probation_id (here there are multiple records, so do i use another array here?)
```

single example case:
resource_id=1
output:
clyde(resources.first_name),4(probation_hr.hr_id),M1(probation_hr.month_id),1(probation_hr.probation_id),array(records from probation_feedback table where probation_id=1):

```
 1           6          null,
 1           7          null
 1           8          null
 1           null       1
```

how do i do this in one query?

is it possible?

if not possible than how do i do it?
do i use 2d array?

im using php and mysql

thanx in advance

Comment: what?? can you reduce your question to an understandable main problem? And format code/table-defs as such to be seperated from comments? (click `?` at right top to see how)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I posing as an answer. You will get the result from above mentioned tables using joins. Kindly find the below query to get the result:

```
SELECT r.first_anme
     , p_h.month_id
     , p_h.probation_id
     , p_h.hr_id
     , p_f.* 
  FROM probation_feedback p_f 
  LEFT 
  JOIN probation_hr p_h 
    ON p_f.prob_id = p_h.probation_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN resources r 
    ON r.res_id = p_h.res_id;
```

Here you will get multiple result, as probation_feedback table have multiple records consisting same prob_id. I don't think you would get records from probation_feedback table as an array, but instead you will get multiple lines of result. Let me know, if it works or not. Thank you